# What is the difference between WS_POPUP and WS_OVERLAPPED without titlebar?

Tags: c++, winapi

If I handle `WM_NCCALCSIZE` for a window with the style `WS_OVERLAPPED`, I just simply return `0` when the `WPARAM` value is `TRUE`. This removes the window borders.

What is the difference between doing that, rather than creating a `WS_POPUP` window? Are the actual frames different if I try to extend the frames using `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea?` And when should I try to use each style?

Comment: http://adelzhang.blogspot.com/2011/05/wspopup-wsoverlapped-wschild.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WS_POPUP is not nearly as relevant as it once was, it is a hint to the OS that the window is not likely to be long-lived and thus to save the display area under the window rather than require repainting when the window is dismissed. The window handled by the popup menu loop for example, or dialogs. This used to be a major performance benefit (particularly in the days of win16) when used appropriately, I am not aware of any difference in the actual mechanics between overlapped and popup windows.